# Android - ActionBarSherlock custom view in a MenuItem

Tags: android, radio-button, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I have a `MenuItem` list, and I wanna set the view of each `MenuItem` with a `TextView` and a `RadioButton`, but for default it just allow me set the view for `Checkable` (`menuItem.setCheckable(true)`). Exists any way to set this `MenuItems` on a `RadioButton` option or set an custom view, where I can custom the view for `RadioButton` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for set an custom View, but to resolve my issue I did something like this:

```
subMenu.setGroupCheckable(groupId, true, true);
```

But only after the subMenu items are all added.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a few days before yours: [Custom views in actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554524/custom-views-in-actionbar/12596803)

[ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html)

Answer (score 0):

try something similar like this on onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    MenuItem spin = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);
    spin.setActionView(channelsSpinner);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: try  youritem =  menu.findItem(R.id.your_item)
     youritem.setActionView(yourRadioButton)